# I want o dynamically change a style sheet using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<link href="style1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="dynamic_css" />
```

I want to change the above stylesheet to style1.css if the window is above 950px

I tried the code below.

```
$("#dynamic_css").before( "<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css")
```

Comment: Take some time to proof read, it will make a massive difference.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but this will be closed as offtopic, duplicated, and more

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I believe your edit to the post fixed some of the errors in the code provided.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I edit the subject and the code indentation. I see your last edition, is better ;)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude you added `<div>` tags in `.prepend()`.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova no! I don't modify the original code. I only indent it. The code was not indented and it forms a normal text block instead a code block , so tags like `<div>` was seen hidden.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude sorry, my bad then :)

Comment: Doesn't matter , good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what jQuery has to do with this, as you've tagged it with CSS I figure a CSS solution won't hurt.

You need to wrap media queries around the styles you want to show at different resolutions:

```
.class { color: #green; }

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 500px) {

    .class { color: #red; }

}
```

So anything within .class will be coloured green, if the browser window is between 400 and 500 pixels, then it will be coloured red.

You don't need to specify minimum AND maximum widths, just one or the other, i.e.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    // styles in here
}
```

..will take effect when the browser window is 768px wide or wider, and..

```
@media (max-width: 399px) {
    // styles in here
}
```

...will take effect when the browser window is 399px wide or less.